# Travel to USA if visa is issued in other country

Tags: visas, usa, j1-visas

I am Indian national and my J1 visa to USA is issued in Sweden as I work there temporarily. Due to urgent work I want to go to India first and then travel to USA. My question is that, can I travel to USA from India and the country where the visa is issued (Sweden)doesn't matter. Or do I need to enter the USA from Sweden only. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can travel to the USA from wherever you want, the country where your visa was issued is not important.